# Adding a filter to check if a session is valid or not

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Im adding a filter to check if a session is valid or not.

Added the following but get the error

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null
            && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
```

Error:-

```
The method getRequestedSessionId() is undefined for the type ServletRequest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `getRequestedSessionId` (and `isRequestedSessionIdValid`) is declared on the [`HttpServletRequest` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestedSessionId%28%29). You're trying to invoke the method on a reference of type [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html). If you know the referenced object will really be a `HttpServletRequest`, cast it in order to invoke the method.

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
if (httpRequest.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !httpRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Have a question - When it is casted, I'm sure it will copy all the attributes of the ServletRequest to HttpServletRequest. What happens if there are more attributes in ServletRequest or vice-versa?

Comment: @user1050619 Casting doesn't do anything to an object. Casting applies to values and the value here is the reference to the object. The object is the exact same. You're just looking at it differently, as having type `HttpServletRequest` instead of `ServletRequest`.